# VScode Install @types Quick Fix for TypeScript

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have been trying to install types with the new update of Vscode Install @types Quick Fix for TypeScript, but still not working and also the typesearch plugin fails.

please any solution on how to fix this problem.

Comment: Please file an issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report that should be filed against VS Code